# Refreshing data in listviews in Fragments when an activity is closed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I have an application with two activities. The first contains a tab bar with three fragments in it. Clicking on a button in the fragment loads the second activity.

When the second activity is dismissed, either by the back button or by the Up Navigation, I need to refresh the data in two list views in the main activity's fragments.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The key is understanding the `Activity` and `Fragment` [lifecycles](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html). When the first `Activity` and `Fragment` return from to the foreground several events are called such as `onResume()` this is one spot your refresh could occur at.

Comment: But OnResume() is for the Activity, no? How could I then call functions in each fragment to update the list views?

Comment: `onResume()` is an event in both `Fragment` and `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start your second Activity with `startActivityForResult`, and in `onActivityResult`, refresh your fragments.

Answer (score 0):

When your second activity dismissed, the first one brought to front, right? This causes one of the tab fragment to show again. In your fragment you probably have a List Adapters for your list views.

Try this in your fragment:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```